# Convert Mysql timestamp to Python's datetime

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a table in MySQL that has a column with `TIMESTAMP` datatype.
This is what the value on that column looks like on MySQL.

[image]

When I try to fetch that `InstallTs` column using Python, this is the result I get.

> Tue Apr 26 03:10:02 SGT 2016

This is the code I have for converting it to the same format as the one from MySQL 
print mysql_time

```
mysql_time = 'Tue Apr 26 03:10:02 SGT 2016'
print datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mysql_time), '%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %Z %Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This is the result I get:

```
2018-02-06 03:10:02
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why it is different from the one I fetch from MySQL?

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: uhh, result from mysql is `APRIL 26, 2016` when i try to convert to a different format it returns `2018-02-06 03:10:02` @VikasNehaOjha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `%m` as the third argument which is month.  There is no 26th month, so it is advancing the time forward to compensate.

This should most likely be `%d`.